# how to erase text from window

Tags: c++, text, sfml

I wanted to make some clicker, and everything has gone easily but, I can't erase text from window. By *I can't erase* I mean that if i draw some text(int converted to string to be specific). "123" for example. And I want to change that "123" text to new one, let's say "124", the old text is still visible on the window, and I don't know how to erase it. And yes, I've looked for how to do that on internet, but i only found *.erase()* class and *remove_last_char()* that doesn't work for me.

I am using the string stream to convert int to string. And i don't think that the code that i am using is necessary here.

Edit - Here's my code(And sorry if i am doing something wrong but i am new to stack overflow):

```
stringstream scash;    
Text text; 
text.setCharacterSize(16); 
text.setFillColor(Color::White); 
text.setPosition(0, 50); 
text.setFont(font);`  

while (window.isOpen())     
{   
text.setString(scash.str());          
window.clear();         
button.setPosition(W_width / 2, W_height / 2);         
window.draw(button);         
window.draw(text); 
 
    if(//button/mouse collision check here) 
    {       
        if(Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))     
        {       
        cash = cash + 1;        
        scash << cash;      
        } 
    } 
    window.display(); 
}
```

Comment: Without seeing some code it's hard to know what's going on. Normally the entire screen is cleared and redrawn every frame so the old value should disappear and be replaced by the new one.

Comment: The problem here is that the window is cleared every frame, but old text is still somehow visible, and i don't know why.

Here some code:
`
window.clear();
window.draw(text); //it is in a loop ofcourse
window.display();


`

Comment: Are you sure the window is cleared every frame? Are you sure you aren't still drawing the old text?

Comment: I'm not so I'll give you my code so you can check it


`int cash = 0;
stringstream scash;
    
Text text;
text.setCharacterSize(16);
text.setFillColor(Color::White);
text.setPosition(0, 50);
text.setFont(font);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
     text.setString(scash.str());

        window.clear();
        button.setPosition(W_width / 2, W_height / 2);
        window.draw(button);
        window.draw(text);

if(//button/mouse collision check here)
{ 
 if(Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
 {
  cash = cash + 1;
  scash << cash;   
 }
}
window.display();
}`

Comment: Please add the code to your question, don't post it as comment.

Comment: You should edit your question to include more details like code. Comments aren't meant for that.

Comment: You should clear the stringstream before you add the new value. `scash.str("");`

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped, now the code works as it should. :D